# Read configuration file to populate name of package in conanfile.py

Tags: python, conan

I have a `conanfile.py` in the root of my repository. Next to it is a configuration file. To not repeat myself, I would like to read this configuration file in my `conanfile.py` and populate some properties of the `ConanFile` object, including the `name` of the package:

```
class MyConan(ConanFile):
    name = # ... load from configuration file
```

`conanfile.py` is executed form multiple locations and I haven't found a consistent way to find out the location of my configuration file. When executed in the repo, then I can use `__file__`. In the conan cache however, I don't know how to put my configuration file into the `export` folder or how to retrieve the exported sources directory early enough during initialization of the class. Is it even possible to achieve loading of meta data in the `conanfile.py`?

Comment: I'm trying to use the approach described here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#init
I was getting "Permission denied" errors when I exported my configuration file, until I removed the readonly flag of this file. Looks sort of similar to this issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/3638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple and straight forward after I had removed the readonly flag from the file `data.json` (otherwise exporting will fail with "Permission denied", at least on Windows):

```
import json
import os

from conans import ConanFile, load


class MyConan(ConanFile):
    exports = "data.json"

    def init(self):
        data = json.loads(load(os.path.join(self.recipe_folder, "data.json")))
        self.name = data["name"]
```

This solution is documented here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#init